# Rails 3 - link/button to run ajax request without redirecting

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, jquery

What's the best way for a link to run an ajax command (I'm using jquery in Rails 3.1)?  So far I am trying to use a link to run code via the controller action "update_me."

`views/products/new.html.erb` has the following line:

```
<%= link_to "Update", :action => 'update_me' %>
```

In my products controller, I have:

```
def update_me
    logger.debug 'ajax code will be here'
end
```

But this gives a missing template error:

Template is missing

> Missing template products/update_me, application/update_me with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/code/preevio/app/views" * "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/devise-1.4.3/app/views"

Why do I need to have a `update_me.html.erb` in my views? I assume that's what they want.  Can't I just launch the code in the controller action/method without having to have a view for it?  Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Does the update_me action POST or GET data

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is a bit late, but I post it for anyone else who may get here trying to do something similar.

If you change your line of html to

```
<%= link_to "Update", :action => 'update_me', :remote => true %>
```

That should have the link to the provided action and do the ajax call for you.

You can look at the provided link to see the docs.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: As a side note you will will also need the 

render :nothing => true

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails has convention over configuration, Rails expects an appropriate view for the action in the controller.

If you want to render nothing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

```
render :nothing => true
```

Comment: this brings me to a blank page which is products/update_me. how can I prevent any type of redirection?

Comment: why dont you then just use jquery to make the ajax call? i think $.ajax("<%= link_to "Update", :action => 'update_me' %>")